# Python-barcode. How can i change a path to save the barcode?

Tags: python

I use [python-barcode](https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/) for creating barcode but it saves them in the same directory where the program is located. How do I change the save directory to the desktop or any other selectable directory.

```
def codecreator(barcode_numbers):
            desk = "\\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\\"
            path = desk + barcode_numbers
# Creation barcode
            img = barcode.get ('ean13', barcode_numbers, writer = ImageWriter ())
            img.save(path)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue you're having is that Python Barcode can not find the directory and is defaulting to the working directory as Python can not resolve "%USERPROFILE%" in a string.

Try retrieving the *%USERPROFILE%* env variable like this:

```
import os
desk = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + "\\Desktop"
```